# How can I use a button to send an email based on the content of each cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on my Google Sheets to try to automate this tedious task. Here's the [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z-0_QtpPrsjQIDzIpd-RrmXYQhoqGZeLdJ3M-eXZ51k/edit?usp=sharing)

Can someone help me make a button that sends an email like this:

**details should come from the "Projects" sheet

Subject: C7 Here's the latest on our project D7!

Message Body:

Latest Update:

Y7

Project Name: D7, E7
Status: F7
Date Started: G7
Target Completion Date: H7
Will be completed in: I7 days
Work Permits: TIM - S7, End-customer - T7, Others - U7
Cross Connect Details: From Q7 to R7 under Service ID: P7
Test Results: V7
3PP Service ID: W7
Billing Effective Date: X7

**if no value yet, the email should display "NA"
**trigger is the envelop on Z7, when clicked, should send an email to: carlo.reyes.timcorp@gmail.com and should send another email to the person who clicked the button as receipt
**each cell in Z7 should have the same envelope icon and should be able to send an email based on the content of the row

THANK YOU SO MUCH IN ADVANCE.

```
function sendEmail() {
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Projects").getRange("B2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
    var message = 'This is your Alert email!';
    var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
    MailApp.sendEmail("carlo.reyes.timcorp@gmail.com", subject, message);
}
```

This is working but this is not the result that I'm looking for.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: Hello. Have you seen the link I shared? That's the input. If you will notice, there is a Send column on cell Z7. What I'd like to do is when I clicked that, it will send an email like the email body I shared. Example, the email subject should display whatever in cell C7 and cell D7. For example: Subject: [TIM-SRCT-PRJ-2023-0001] Here's the latest on our project Project 1 at Site 1.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, although I saw your Spreadsheet, unfortunately, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.